# Insert TypefacedTextView in front of another TypefacedTextView horizontal Linnerlayout

Tags: android

I have a Linear layout with `RatingBar` and `TypefacedTextView` in `horizontal` orientation. How can i replace `RatingBar` with another `TypefacedTextView` programmatically?

Here is my code to create `TypefacedTextView`

```
public void addReplaceText() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TypefacedTextView starText = new TypefacedTextView(getContent().getContext());
        starText.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
        starText.setTextSize(17);
        starText.setPadding(5, 3, 0, 3);
        starText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        starText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        starText.setText("111");
        ((LinearLayout) ratingWrapper).addView(starText);
    }
```

I tried:

```
distance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
addReplaceText()
distance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but the added ReplacedText still at the end.

**layout.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ratingWrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/hotel_card_star_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        tools:rating="3"/>

    <TypefacedTextView
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        tools:text="0.1 mi"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `addView(starText, 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/hotel_card_star_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:rating="3" />

        <TypefacedTextView
            android:id="@+id/another_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="0.1 mi"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TypefacedTextView
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        tools:text="0.1 mi"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

now hide and show hotel_card_star_rating or another_one as per your requirement.